# How to open a zip file and extract a string and an integer from the file?

Tags: python, string, zip

I stumbled upon stackoverflow while googling and learning python. I am an absolute beginner in coding and python. I started with the basics and some intermediate python 10 days ago and I am very excited to keep learning. I realized that the best way to learn is by practice. I have some data in a zip file.

1. I want to open the zip file using python, then
2. extract a specific string `titanium`,
   output `Name=titanium`,
3. a value `charge = 0`

I didn't know where to start for I have only learned the basics. But I tried the following. What I learned in introductory python in the past 10 days was importing a regular file but not a zip file. Is the code below correct? I would appreciate a feedback. As for looking for a specific string after opening the file. How can I look for a specific string and charge value?

```
from zipfile import ZipFile
    hp_object = "hp-dell.zip"
    with ZipFile(hp_object, 'r') as zip:
        zip.printdir()
        print('extracting all files')
        zip.extractall()
```

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow. So far you are on the right track in extracting all files from the zip-archive. What files do you have in this .zip?

Comment: Zip files are "archives" containing other files, so your question doesn't make much sense because you are asking how to extract specific data types from one.